# Kotlin program throwing a nullPointerException when setting a clickListener to a button defined in an inflated XML, not sure where to go

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, button

I'm attempting to teach myself Android Development and Kotlin, and I've been stuck on this issue for a while. Because I'm relatively new, I'm almost certain it's just something I don't understand, and would really appreciate any help. `parameterize_button` is defined in the `fragment_dashboard` XML file. This XML is inflated within `DashboardFragment.kt`, but it still throws:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.caelussidekick, PID: 15355
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.caelussidekick.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onCreateView
```

Here's my XML, and I know it is parameterize_button because I haven't set any onClickListeners to any of the other buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/parameterize_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/parameters_buttion" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/outputs_header"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dv_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/empty_string"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dv_unit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/dv"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dv_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/dv_button" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/isp_value"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/empty_string"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/isp_unit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/isp"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/isp_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/isp_button" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here's my DashboardFragment.kt. This is part of the default bottom navigation activity in Android Studio, which is why a lot of the code is commented out.

```
package com.example.caelussidekick.ui.dashboard

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.caelussidekick.R
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.net.Uri
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_dashboard.*

class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
//        dashboardViewModel =
//                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
        val output = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)


//        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_dashboard)
//        dashboardViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
//            textView.text = it
//        })
        this.parameterize_button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(activity, ParamActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        return output

    }


}
```

Thanks for any help! I'm honestly at a loss. I've looked on stackoverflow extensively, and have tried moving the button to the main activity, using nullable modifiers, and making it a field in the class, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthetic view bindings are not valid until `onCreateView()` returns - it doesn't know about your `output` inflated View until it is actually set as the view on the Fragment.

Therefore you can move your code to `onViewCreated()`, which is the method that happens immediately after `onCreateView()` (you should generally not be doing anything but inflating your view in `onCreateView()`):

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        this.parameterize_button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(activity, ParamActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parametrizedbtn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.parameterize_button)
```

parmetrizedbtn.setOnClickLIstener{
val intent = Intent(view.context,ParamActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
}
may work for your